# Is there an authentic Hadith about tasting salt before meal?

Tags: hadith, sunnah

I have heard that tasting a pinch of salt before meal is sunnah. Is it stated anywhere in the Six Authentic books of Hadith? Give full description.

Comment: There is no authentic narration of this in any of the six and this is considered fabricated. Would you still want to know the details/description?

Comment: I've read an indication from Shi'a sources that some of that there is a recommendation of some of their imams (maybe even the prophet himself) regarding salt.